# Как делают сложные слайдер с разными эффектами анимации на каждый элемент слайда

Tags: jquery

Часто встречаю слайдеры с эффектами наподобие этого http://ruformat.ru/ особенно интересен второй слайд с большим количеством отельных элементов с самостоятельной анимацией.

В чём суть вопроса, мне интересно существует какая-то библиотека (расширение для jquery) помогающая делать такие слайдеры или это чистый "самопал" (т.е. каждый слайд это набор отдельных функций, анимаций css стилей и всё как-то последовательно запцскается)?

Приведённый пример подробно не разбирал и пока не понял как он делается. Но брать его как истину в последней инстанции пока не хочу. Хочется узнать мнение профессионалов.

Comment: второе, к разным элементам подключены различные анимации.

Comment: @Jean-Claude ясно, ну да я глянул более подробно. Однако меня не покидает уверенность что где-то есть библиотечка для создания подобных штук более упорядочено (с минимумом самопала).